# Doubt in derivation of the classical electron radius

Tags: electrostatics, electrons

At the "derivation" section of [wikipedia page for the classical electron radius](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electron_radius) I am not able to follow the last step (citation follows):

*Integrating for $r$ from zero to the final radius $r$ yields the expression for the total energy $U$ necessary to assemble the total charge $q$ into a uniform sphere of radius $r$: $$U=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\space\frac{3}{5}\space \frac{q^2}{r}$$*

Which are the final steps to reach that concrete expression? I have tried to derive it from the previous statements, and searched a bit through the web to find how it is done, but unsuccessfully.

I would appreciate a detailed answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would argue that you should find a electromagnetism book. This is a common calculation, the energy of a homogenous charged sphere. One thing that is maybe not explained is that $\rho=3 q/ 4\pi r^2 $ (total charge over volume of a sphere), $r$ being the total radius not the integration variable.

Comment: @Mauricio is correct, but the denominator is $r^3$ not $r^2$

Comment: Sorry it is indeed $\rho=3q/4\pi r^3$